# Accessing a forwarded port from Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, vagrant, portforwarding

I have a Vagrant box which runs a nodejs server with port 3000 which I have forwarded to my host with `vagrant ssh -- -L 3000:localhost:3000`. For some reason, using 10.0.2.2:3000 on the Android Emulator does not reach this server. Is there anything else that I have to do to access an already-forwarded ip and port from within an Android Emulator instance?

It does work from my host, but not within Android Emulator.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be my application's issue. From nc in adb shell I can access the interface in question.